# Laravel how pass and read param from one route to another

Tags: laravel, routes

how pass and get params from one route to another

```
return redirect('/registration')->with('some_params', $input);
```

and here is `registrationController` index method:

```
public function index(){
     $some_params = Request::get('some_params'); //no result 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`with` method flashes data to the session, you have to retrieve the data using the `Session::get` method.

```
public function index(){
 $some_params = Session::get('some_params');
}
```